# HTML ext js fieldsets

Tags: html, extjs, fieldset

This is my first experience with ext js and I use ext js designer tool.
I have created 3 fieldsets each having different input format but the same input for backend.
E.g. search by selecting checkboxes
Or search by type in full data
Or search by type in keywords in data

The user would use only one of these and there is one common submit.
I want something like this:
If one fieldset has focus others are disabled and cleared of any entries.
How to implement this in JavaScript and using ext js?

Answer (score 1):

First I have to say [Sencha API Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) are your friend. It's not clear which fields you are using but all fields have events that you can use for that like `change`, `focus`, and many more. You should also take a look at the [Sencha ExtJS Examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) and the [Learning-Resources](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Learn_About_the_Ext_JavaScript_Library)

If you still don't get it to work post the code what you have tried so far and you will get further help.